# Request data fails Laravel validation even though it shouldn't

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error:

> the given data failed to pass validation.  /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/ptm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#89

When I look at the `$data`, it's filled with:

```
array:1 [
  "{"_token":"Z5fv3XpoNwoMdJPRP16I09bZeX7Pb6raH30K8n3b","name":"test","id":"","email":"test@example_com","password":"testing"}"
]
```

Here's the code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

        $data = $request->all();            

        $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required',
                            'email' => 'required',
                            'password' => 'required'
                        ]);

  try
  {
    $this->user->create($request);
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    return json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Something went wrong, please try again later.'));
  }

  return json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'User successfully saved!'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly saying that the `validate()` method is throwing an exception. If you want it to not to throw an exception, update your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class and add `ValidationException` to the `$dontReport` array:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class, // <= Here
    ];
```

Read more:
[Documentation how to migrate from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

Or you can leave it as it is, and handle the exception in a new `catch` block:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'     => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $this->user->create($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false, 
            'message' => 'There were validation errors.',
        ], 400);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false, 
            'message' => 'Something went wrong, please try again later.'
        ], 400);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true, 
        'message' => 'User successfully saved!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: But why is it throwing a exception. All the fields are filled. this is not a migration, but a new application with laravel 5.3

Comment: SepehrLajevardi, thanks four your sollution, But i don;t understand why it is  not validated, because all the fields are filled. So why?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed that. Let me see. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm unfortunate to say that I couldn't reproduce your issue. I tested it and it works pretty fine, without any exceptions, in a brand new Laravel 5.3 installation.

Comment: Ok. how can i debug this to find what is going wrong?

Comment: Work directly with the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` and inspect it for clues instead of using controller's `validate()`.

Comment: do you have a example how to use the Illuminate\Validation\Validator

Comment: Try this instead; Override `formatValidationErrors()` in your controller and `dd($validator->errors()->all())` to start looking for clues. See **Customizing The Flashed Error Format** section in Laravel's validation docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: Would you please hit your controller method and pass data using simple GET parameters? `example.dev/test?name=test&email=test@example.com&password=testing` and see if the error occurs?

Comment: ok. i have to leave now. I;ll try it and let you know. if you have other sugesstions or sollutions......

Comment: hi SepehrLajevardi: this is the get: jquery.js:7845 GET http://ptm.app:8000/user/create?{%22_token%22:%22voMeEEWR2Cg2zsv9rjBq884ia0…22:%22%22,%22email%22:%22test@example.com%22,%22password%22:%22testing%22}.  Still the same error...

Comment: You're sending data as a stringified json object over to Laravel. That's not a standard way to send data over http and sure enough, Laravel does not support it. Please use query strings instead. Here's an example: `ptm.app:8000/user/create?name=test&email=test@example.com&password=testing`

Comment: Hi SepehrLajevardi, i'm following this tutorial http://www.mariogallegos.com/tutorials/crud-custom-form, in step 8 he is using this:  data: JSON.stringify($('#book-form').formToObject(''))

Comment: He's `POST`ing to the endpoint and it's OK to use `JSON.stringify` instead of manually saying `{"name": "test", ...}`. But that **might** be a possible source of your problem here as well. For testing purposes, please use your browser and simply visit `ptm.app:8000/user/create?name=test&email=test@example.com&pa‌​ssword=testing`. See what's inside `$request->all()` and see whether the validation passes or not. No ajax request please.

Comment: i get the following error now: FatalThrowableError in ValidatesRequests.php line 50:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to ptm\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/ptm/app/Http/Controllers/usercontroller.php on line 40

Comment: I have in my usercontroller the folling code:                                 $data = $request->all();
\Debugbar::error($data);    $this->validate($data, ['name' => 'required',
                              'email' => 'required',
                              'password' => 'required'
                            ]);
]

Comment: $data has the values: array:3 [
  "name" => "test"
  "email" => "test@example.com"
  "pa‌​‌​ssword" => "testing"
]

Comment: You have to pass the `$request` object to `validate()`, not the `$data` array.

Comment: I did pass the $request object. this is the code:    $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required',
                              'email' => 'required',
                              'password' => 'required'
                            ]);

Comment: So, your latest error (`FatalThrowableError in ValidatesRequests.php line 50`) is solved. Assuming that you're passing data as GET querystring, what's inside `$data`? Does the validation pass? If it doesn't, I can't tell you what to do withour further seeing the code. Sorry.

Comment: I don't have the error  (FatalThrowableError in ValidatesRequests.php line 50) any more.  
$data has the values: array:3 [ "name" => "test" "email" => "test@example.com" "pa‌​‌​ssword" => "testing" ]  and i still get the same error

Comment: i now get this error: [10:59:58] LOG.error: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to ptm\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/ptm/app/Http/Controllers/usercontroller.php on line 40 in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/ptm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php:50

Comment: Your `$request` object is invalid (null), have you changed the method signature? It must be: `public function create(Request $request)`.

Comment: No, i did not. How can i print the $request obj. print_r doesn't or var_dump doesn't show anything on screen

Comment: `dd($request)` if it's present.

Comment: Hi sepehr, i tried did but with no luck. Nothing is display on screen.

Comment: No clues, I can't say anything from these chats without seeing the code :/

Comment: Hi Sepehr, Sorry for the late reaction. Been sick a few days, I'll stop this home project for now and pick it later in. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You might check the blade template for the correct case on the variables. e.g. 'name', 'email' and 'password' are case sensitive and the blade template case of the variables must match the controller's  case for the variables.

Comment: Hi Coders2055, i'm following this tutorial mariogallegos.com/tutorials/crud-custom-form. What i want is to see what is in the request. Why is it complaning about invalid request in the controller?